# Why is Class<T extends Base> not applicable to Class<Base>?

Tags: java, generics

I am in the creation of a small application and I stumbled over the following problem.

There is a `List<Class<MyCustomBaseClass>>` in my application and a function with the signature `public <T extends MyCustomBaseClass> void addClass(Class<T> clazz)`.
The `AddClass` should put the `clazz` into the List. But I get the following error there:

> `The method add(Class<MyCustomBaseClass>) in the type List<Class<MyCustomBaseClass>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<T>)`

Here are my 3 classes as simplified as I could make them:

```
// Program.java
package me.mischa.stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Program {

    private List<Class<MyCustomBaseClass>> _listOfClasses;
    private static Program _instance;

    public Program() {
        _listOfClasses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.addClass(MyCustomChildClass.class);
    }

    public <T extends MyCustomBaseClass> void addClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        _listOfClasses.add(clazz);
    }

}
```

.

```
// MyCustomBaseClass.java
package me.mischa.stackoverflow;

public class MyCustomBaseClass {

}
```

.

```
// MyCustomChildClass.java
package me.mischa.stackoverflow;

public class MyCustomChildClass extends MyCustomBaseClass {

}
```

The error is at the line `_listOfClasses.add(clazz);`

I do not understand why `<T extends MyCustomBaseClass>` should not be compatible with `<MyCustomBaseClass>`

Comment: A `List<T extends Animal>` can point to a `List<Dog>`. But a `List<Dog>` does not allow `Cat`s to be inserted, in contrast to a `List<Animal>`. Both lists behave differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's generics are invariant.  That means that, as a type parameter, `Class<MyCustomBaseClass>` means exactly that, no Class object representing a subclass of `MyCustomBaseClass` is allowed.

In your `addClass` method, you've only given an upper bound on `T` when defining it -- `T` could be a subclass of `MyCustomBaseClass`, e.g. your class `MyCustomChildClass`.  The compiler disallows this call because of the mismatch.

You can widen what's allowed in `_listOfClasses` by providing a matching upper bound, which will allow the method `addClass` to compile.

```
private List<Class<? extends MyCustomBaseClass>> _listOfClasses;
```

Incidentally, because it doesn't really matter exactly what type `T` is in `addClass`, you can remove it and use a wildcard.

```
public void addClass(Class<? extends MyCustomBaseClass> clazz) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's generics are invariant. There's a reason for that. Imagine the following code (NOTE: `Number` is a supertype of both `Integer` and `Double`):

```
List<Double> doublesOnly = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Number> numbers = doublesOnly;
numbers.add(new Integer(5));
Double d = doublesOnly.get(0);
```

In the above, *if* it had been valid java, you are assigning an Integer to a Double, which is a problem because an Integer isn't a Double. This is why in actual fact, if you attempt to compile the above, it won't work; the second line is marked as invalid java, because a `List<Double>` cannot be assigned to a `List<Number>`. There is a solution:

```
List<Double> doublesOnly = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<? extends Number> numbers = doublesOnly;
numbers.add(new Integer(5));
Double d = doublesOnly.get(0);
```

This time, line 3 is the error: You cannot add anything to a `List<? extends Something>`, other than `null`. There's no way to fix this code and that's good because we're doing something fundamentally bad.

The solution in your specific case is two-fold:

1. More generally you should avoid the notion of using `Class<?>` in your APIs. Generally, use factories instead.
2. If you must, try something like: `List<Class<? extends MyCustomBaseClass>>`. Yes, 2 extends. You can add a `Class<MyCustomChildClass>` to this list.